# Read the last line of a CSV file and extract one value

Tags: node.js, csv

New to Node.js and trying to pull a value from the very last line of a CSV file. Here is the CSV:

```
Unit ID,Date,Time,Audio File
Log File Created,3/6/2013,11:18:25 AM,file:\\\C:\Users\Ben\Documents\1_03-06-2013_1114-50.mp3
1,3/6/2013,11:20:24 AM,file:\\\C:\AlertLog\1_03-06-2013_1120-24.mp3
1,3/6/2013,11:20:39 AM,file:\\\C:\AlertLog\1_03-06-2013_1120-24.mp3
```

The part I am trying to grab is `file:\\\C:\AlertLog\1_03-06-2013_1120-24.mp3` - preferably getting rid of the `file:\\\` part.

Sorry that I do not have any code to show, just have a few hours of experience with Node.js and cannot seem to find any docs on how to accomplish something like this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Regular file

Read the file like a regular file, split the file contents into lines, take the last line, split by a comma and take the last part.

```
var fs = require('fs'); // file system module

fs.readFile('/path/to/file.csv', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var lines = data.trim().split('\n');
    var lastLine = lines.slice(-1)[0];

    var fields = lastLine.split(',');
    var audioFile = fields.slice(-1)[0].replace('file:\\\\', '');

    console.log(audioFile);
});
```

[File System module documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_encoding_callback)

### CSV parser

You can also use the [node-csv-parser](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parser) module.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require('csv');

csv()
 .from.stream(fs.createReadStream('/path/to/file.csv'))
 .to.array(function(data, count) {
    var lastLine = data.slice(-1)[0];
    var audioFile = lastLine.slice(-1)[0].replace('file:\\\\', '');
    console.log(audioFile);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this just gave me "3," which I tracked down to be the 3 at the end of .mp3. The replace threw an error `Object 3 has no method 'replace'

Comment: Change `data.slice(-1)` to `lines.slice(-1)`

Comment: Okay now we're getting somewhere! The CSV parser method output the last line if I removed the .replace - still throwing that error. But it is the entire line, not just the last part..

Comment: `lines` is not defined in the function, so that throws an error. Changing `function(data, count)` to `function(lines, count)` and then `data.slice(-1)` to `lines.slice(-1)` does not make much sense, since it's doing the same thing?

Comment: Change `data.slice(-1)` to `lines.slice(-1)` in the first code example.

Comment: Just figured that out. It looks like it's turning the line into an object and then looking to see if that object has the next thing as a method. Here is the error - `TypeError: (CSV line here) has no method 'split'`

Comment: `array.slice(-1)` returns an array. So you have to use `array.slice(-1)[0]` to get the last element. Or, if you don't care about the array anymore, you can use `array.pop()` instead.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! Saved me a ton of frustration. I'm a PHP developer and really had to scramble to figure out how to deal with a project that is outside of my usual work. Node.js looks awesome, just haven't had very much time to really study it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 9):

I did it by reading the file backwards until the last line was read:

**Update 2022** (use modern javascript and read buffer only once)

```
import { open } from 'node:fs/promises';
import path from 'node:path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __dirname = path.dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
const fileName = path.join(__dirname, 'test.txt');

async function readLastLine(name) {
  var line = '';
  var chunkSize = 200 // how many characters to read from the end of file
  const fd = await open(name);
  const st = await fd.stat();
  const buf = Buffer.alloc(chunkSize);
  const len = buf.length;
  const { bytesRead, buffer } = await fd.read(buf, 0, len, st.size - len)
  for (let i = len - 1; i > -1; i--) {
    const isEol = buffer[i] === 0x0a // 0x0a == '\n'
    const isCtrl = buffer[i] < 0x20 // 0-31 are ASCII control characters
    if (isEol && line.length > 0) {
      break;
    } else if (!isCtrl && !isEol) {
      line = String.fromCharCode(buffer[i]) + line;
    }
  }
  fd.close();
  return line;
}

try {
  const line = await readLastLine(fileName)
  console.log(line);
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

**Old 2014 answer**

```
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var fileName = path.join(__dirname, 'test.txt');
    var readLastLine = function(name, callback) {
        fs.stat(name, function(err, stat) {
            fs.open(name, 'r', function(err, fd) {
                if(err) throw err;
                var i = 0;
                var line = '';
                var readPrevious = function(buf) {
                    fs.read(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, stat.size-buf.length-i, function(err, bytesRead, buffer) {
                        if(err) throw err;
                        line = String.fromCharCode(buffer[0]) + line;
                        if (buffer[0] === 0x0a) { //0x0a == '\n'
                            callback(line);
                        } else {
                            i++;
                            readPrevious(new Buffer(1));
                        }
                    });
                }
                readPrevious(new Buffer(1));
            });
        });
    }
    readLastLine(fileName, function(line) {
        console.log(line);
    });
```

Comment: The only problem with this, is that if it already contains an "\n" at the end of the last line, it won't pick up the rest and leave immediately on the callback. You have to check, for instance, with a variable (e.g.: "newLinesCounter") for the system's EOL, from "os" package. It would be something like: `if (newLineCounter === 2) callback(line);`

Comment: @RickStanley I updated my answer to modern javascript. Also that old code hurt my eyes, so I got rid of recursion and reading files over and over again. :)