# Read the last line of a CSV file and extract one row

Tags: javascript, eof

I am writing a javascpript program to read data from a CSV file and place it in variables, to ultimately be displayed in HTML. This file will be appended to at the end of the file by another program.  I would like to read in the last line only.

Example data:
Date, Data1, Data2, Data3

I have found other code to read in one value from the last line...  [Read the last line of a CSV file and extract one value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15256290/read-the-last-line-of-a-csv-file-and-extract-one-value)

Can I just remove this from that code:

```
var fields = lastLine.split(',');
var audioFile = fields.slice(-1)[0].replace('file:\\\\', '')
```

Thanks!

Here is a code example of what I was going to use:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 // AJAX in the data file
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "file:///home/tech/Desktop/Test/data.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
        });

    // Let's process the data from the data file
    function processData(data) {
        var lines = data.trim().split('\n');
        var lastLine = lines.slice(-1)[0];

        //Set up the data arrays
        var date = [];
        var data1 = [];  
        var data2 = [];
        var data3 = [];


        for (var j=1; j<lines.length; j++) {
        var values = lines[j].split(','); // Split up the comma 
        seperated values
           // We read the key,1st, 2nd and 3rd rows 
           date.push(values[0]); // Read in as string
           // Recommended to read in as float, since we'll be doing 
           some operations on this later.
           data1.push(parseFloat(values[1])); 
           data2.push(parseFloat(values[2]));
           data3.push(parseFloat(values[3]));



        }
    }
})
</script>
</head>
<p>
<H1> This is the 
      <script type="text/javascript"> document.write(date()); 
</script> Date. </H1> <br>
<H1> This is the 
    <script type="text/javascript"> document.write(data1()); 
</script> Data1. </H1> <br>
<H1> This is the
    <script type="text/javascript"> document.write(data2()); 
</script> Data2. </H1> <br>
<H1> This is the
    <script type="text/javascript"> document.write(data3()); 
</script> Data3. </H1> <br>
</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Did that work? Do you have a full example of what you have implemented?

Comment: I have not tried that yet.

Comment: Usually the way Stack Overflow works is you try to do something, then you ask when there's a [mcve] that you can't work past on your own. Right now you have hypothetical code and a hypothetical problem, there's not much to answer until you actually implement something tangible and try it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I apologize!  I'll work on this further and post an update when I have something better you can work from.

Comment: Have you tried this?  What's not working?

Comment: Ok.  I tried running the above code in a web browser locally to test it.  I cannot get it to display the data within the variables.  I set my CSV file up with some sample data and put it in the same directory.  I have also tried using the entire path in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood your question you have to put:

1)in localhost the file csv(test.csv in this example) and file js into serverweb (example XAMPP)
2)your 4 array date, data1, data2, dat3 outside the function.
3) i have used id in all H1 tag and call them with document.getElementById...

I tried the code and works. I have not used the parseFloat because i had text data and no numeric then you remember to modify the code...

the code is the follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

//Set up the data arrays here
        var date = [];
        var data1 = [];
        var data2 = [];
        var data3 = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
 // AJAX in the data file
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        //url: "file:///home/tech/Desktop/Test/test.csv",
        url: "test.csv",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(data) {processData(data);}
        });

    // Let's process the data from the data file
    function processData(data) {
        var lines = data.trim().split('\n');
        var lastLine = lines.slice(-1)[0];
    /*
        //Set up the data arrays
        var date = [];
        var data1 = [];
        var data2 = [];
        var data3 = [];
    */

        for (var j=1; j<lines.length; j++) {
        var values = lines[j].split(','); // Split up the comma
        //seperated values
           // We read the key,1st, 2nd and 3rd rows
           date.push(values[0]); // Read in as string

           // Recommended to read in as float, since we'll be doing
           //some operations on this later.
           data1.push(values[1]);
           data2.push(values[2]);
           data3.push(values[3]);
        }
    //added code
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML="This is the Date. " + date[date.length-1];
    document.getElementById("data1").innerHTML="This is the Data1. " + data1[data1.length-1];
    document.getElementById("data2").innerHTML="This is the Data2. " + data2[data2.length-1];
    document.getElementById("data3").innerHTML="This is the Data3. " + data3[data3.length-1];
    }
})
</script>
</head>
<p>
<H1 id="date"> 
      <script type="text/javascript"> 
</script>  </H1> <br>
<H1 id="data1"> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
</script> . </H1> <br>
<H1 id="data2"> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
</script> </H1> <br>
<H1 id="data3"> 
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
</script></H1> <br>
</p>
</html>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That works!!  I appreciate your efforts!  I hope you have a great day.  Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to display the values in HTML that does not use the heading tag?  I have tried other heading tags but the spacing doesn't fit right.    Other than that it's working perfectly.

Comment: Yes, you can it...for example you can use DIV instead of h1...change the name h1 in DIV...hope this answer tour question...else give me an example...for more style in your web page you can use bootsrap 4...

Answer (score 1):

There's a few issues with your code, which I resolve in my code below

1. your comment `seperated values` is being read as code.
2. your current code won't work if there is only 1 line in the CSV
3. your mid-string usage of `<script>` tags is a very bad habit.

## Solution 1 (in place substitution)

#### HTML

```
<section>
  <h1>This is the <span id="output0"></span> Date.</h1>
  <h1>This is the <span id="output1"></span> Data 1.</h1>
  <h1>This is the <span id="output2"></span> Data 2.</h1>
  <h1>This is the <span id="output3"></span> Data 3.</h1>
</section>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {processData(data)}
  });

  function processData(data) {
    var lines = data.trim().split('\n');
    var lastLine = lines[lines.length - 1].split(',');

    lastLine.forEach(function(value, i) {
      var outputTarget = document.getElementById(`output${i}`);

      if (outputTarget) {
        outputTarget.innerHTML = value
      }
    })
  }
})
```

## Solution 2 (build inside JavaScript)

#### HTML

```
<section id="output"></section>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "data.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {processData(data)}
  });

  function processData(data) {
    var lines = data.trim().split('\n');
    var lastLine = lines[lines.length - 1].split(',');
    var outputTarget = document.getElementById('output')

    lastLine.forEach(function(value, i) {
      var h1 = document.createElement('h1');

      switch(i) {
        case 0:
          h1.innerHTML = `This is the ${value} Date.`;
          break;
        default:
          h1.innerHTML = `This is the ${value} Data ${i}`
      }

      outputTarget.appendChild(h1);
    });
  }
})
```