# Node.js: How to read the last non-empty line only of a txt file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, read-write

Let's say I have a text file called example.exe that is like this:

> Line 1 Stuff
> Line 2 Stuff
> (more lines here)
> Line N (Last Line) Stuff
> (empty line \n)

I want to be able to read the last line of the file only, so in this case "Line N (Last Line) Stuff" and store it inside a string. Also, I do know you can read line-by-line, but I want to reduce runtime and not have out of memory errors occur as the text file gets bigger. Anybody want to help me with this? I would prefer no this done using require('fs').

Comment: Get the file length, and call `read()` with e.g. `offset = length - 1024` and `length = 1024`. Keep reading until you find a non-newline character.

Comment: Reading the file backwards.
Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22464927/3727662) answer.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you store the content in a variable `content` you can split the content by lines...

```
var lines = content.split("\n")
```

...and check if the last line is empty...

```
var lastLine = lines[lines.length-1].length ? lines[lines.length-1] : lines[lines.length-2]
```